# Using Joi and Node, require 1 of 2 fields but not allow both to be present

Tags: node.js, rest, joi

I have 2 fields in a joi object, lets call them "a" and "b" where "a" is an object and "b" is an array of objects. I would like to require 1 of the 2 fields but not allow both, is there a way to do this with joi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `xor`

> Defines an exclusive relationship between a set of keys where one of them is required but not at the same time

https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectxorpeers-options

```
Joi.object().keys({
    a: Joi.object(),
    b: Joi.array()
}).xor('a', 'b')
```